# CqlStorage() not working with Higher Records in PIG(CqlStorage() in pig throws an exception)

Tags: apache-pig, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli, cqlsh

I am using DSE 3.1.2
I am using Pig to store some of the pre-processing results into cql, I have create a table and started my script it worked for few amount of data, when increased few more records its not storing into cassandra, only 90% or the output is storing into cassandra.

here is my script

```
SET default_parallel 10;
result = foreach PreprocUDF generate Primary1,Primary2,col3,col4;
finalresult = foreach result generate TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('Primary1',PreprocUDF::Primary1),TOTUPLE('Primary2',PreprocUDF::Primary2)),TOTUPLE(PreprocUDF::col3,PreprocUDF::col4);

store finalresult into 'cql://conflux/tbl_test?output_query=update+conflux.tbl_test+set+col3+%3D+%3F+,col4+%3D+%3F' using CqlStorage();
```

Now I am getting following error
and 90% of the records are dumped into the cassandra

```
ERROR - 2014-04-29 01:53:49.590; org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation; PriviledgedActionException as:sarrajen cause:java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long (4))
WARN  - 2014-04-29 01:53:49.590; org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child; Error running child
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long (4))
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:465)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:428)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:408)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long (4))
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:248)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long (4))
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_prepared_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:42694)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1724)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1709)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:232)
INFO  - 2014-04-29 01:53:49.764; org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task; Runnning cleanup for the task
```

the lat record it executed is working fine if I insert manually into cassandra.

And everything is working fine if I dump end result into CFS

```
store result into '/testop'
Output(s):
Successfully stored 56347 records in: "/testop"
```

I also tried to dump the data into CFS and then from CFS to Cassandra DB this worked for me. Please let me know where I am wrong. I have created table in CQL with composite key soo I guess we no need to give any comparator and validators as i have specified data types to the coloumns.

```
store result into '/testop'
x = load '/testop' as (Primary1:chararray,Primary2:long,col3:chararray,col4:long);
finalresult = foreach x generate TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('Primary1',Primary1),TOTUPLE('Primary2',Primary2)),TOTUPLE(col3,col4);

    store finalresult into 'cql://conflux/tbl_test?output_query=update+conflux.tbl_test+set+col3+%3D+%3F+,col4+%3D+%3F' using CqlStorage();
```

Now this worked fine.

Please let me know where I am Wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Error of Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long (4))
says that the input data format for long is wrong. There are some bad data in the input field.

You can check you UDF to see how the data is prepared in the right format

Comment: Manually I can insert the record where it is giving me the error.

Comment: I also tried to dump the data into CFS and then from CFS to Cassandra DB this worked for me. Please let me know where I am wrong. I have created table in CQL with composite key soo I guess we no need to give any comparator and validators as i have specified data types to the coloumns.

Comment: Hi alexliu68
can you plz help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Changing Data type in Cassandra from BigInt to varint solved the above problem.